# Using Rails 7 and Taildwincss to put a picture and a card next each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, tailwind-css, wireframe

I'm trying to implement the following design, using Rails 7 with Tailwindcss:

[image: View Design]

I'm new to Taildwincss and I realize there are many ways to achieve this design. However I cannot fully replicate it. This is the code I'm using in my view:

```
<div class="grid gap-1 grid-cols-12 grid-rows-1">
  <% @user.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.photo? %>
      <div class="p-5 col-span-2">
        <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <%= image_tag "user_photo.png", width: 100 %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <%# ToDo: %>
      <%# image_tag user.photo, width: 100 %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="p-5 col-span-10">
      <div class="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-2 text-gray-800"><%= user.name %></h2>
        <p class="text-gray-700 text-right">Number of posts: <%= user.posts.count %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result image]

What could I change to get a bit closer to the wireframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep both the div containing both the image and card in flex and add `item-center` class to it.

Refer to this pseudo code

```
<div class="flex flex-row item-center">
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow">Image</div>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
        card
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the solution code

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-row items-center">
  <div class="p-10">
    <div class="rounded-lg bg-gray-200 p-10 shadow-lg">%></div>
  </div>

  <div class="p-5">
    <div class="rounded-lg bg-gray-200 p-5 shadow-lg">
      <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800">Lily</h2>
      <p class="ml-28 text-right text-gray-700">Number of posts: 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That approach worked better. Thank you for helping out Mohit

Comment: Reach out to me for any doubt in tailwind css